# d3.json what kind of request its making?

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

I am using this d3 plugin: http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/ its loading json data from a local url, I usually add this control in PHP to check if the call is a proper AJAX call:

```
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
```

this checks fails and I was able to backtrace it to the d3.json function.

Can someone explain to me what kind of request is d3.json making?

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

This is the code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    var cal = new CalHeatMap();
    cal.init(
    {
        cellSize:15,
        range: 12,
        domain: "month",
        data: '<?php echo $url; ?>',
        legendHorizontalPosition: 'center',
        legendCellSize: 15
    }
    );
    </script>
```

$url is the url that returns the json.

Comment: Are you trying to update the graph through ajax?

Comment: Nope I'm simply asking what kind of call is d3 making. I edited the code in.

Comment: I'm not aware of what kind of call it does. Sorry! Some one else can help you in this. If you have any problem in loading the `json` file to d3 cal-heatmap. I guess i can help you but not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of it's not clear from the documentation how `data` is processed. So we can take a quick look at the code (Line 2459 src\cal-heatmap.js)

```
switch(typeof source) {
    case "string":
        if (source === "") {
            _callback({});
            return true;
        } else {
            switch(this.options.dataType) {
            case "json":
                d3.json(this.parseURI(source, startDate, endDate), _callback);
                break;
```

When we pass a string rather than an object it checks the extension and uses d3's helper method so should behave just like `d3.json()` which in itself is wraps around `d3.XHR()`. None of the documentation says it sends `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`. A lot of other frameworks do hence why you see it almost the universal method for detecting a AJAX call but it is not required.

Comment: You got me on the right track, is someone stumbles onto this you can change the above line to:

d3.json(this.parseURI(source, startDate, endDate)).header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest").get(_callback);
     
That will send the header.

Comment: Actually I was thinking of changing it in d3 and issuing a pull request once I had found enough information to attach that it was the de facto standard.

Comment: Although looking at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/592 and https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/813 that looks the way it is meant  to be done.